# HANDSHAKE_FAILURE alert received

Tags: java, web-services, security, sslhandshakeexception

I am writing a Java client (on weblogic 10.3) to invoke a secure web service.
I have been provided with a client certificate which I have installed in cacerts, DemoIdentity.jks and DemoTrust,jks
In my weblogic I have set up keystore as DemoIdentity and DemoTrust.
In weblogic console I have set 
"Two Way Client Cert Behavior:" as "Client Certs requested but not enforced".
and for "SSL Listen Port enabled:" I have checked the checkbox.

I get the below exception while trying to access the web service:

```
] FaultActor [null] Detail [<detail><bea_fault:stacktrace xmlns:bea_fault="http:
//www.bea.com/servers/wls70/webservice/fault/1.0.0">javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeEx
ception: [Security:090497]HANDSHAKE_FAILURE alert received from ************** Check both sides of the SSL configuration for mismatches in supported ciphers, supported protocol versions, trusted CAs, and hos
tname verification settings.
        at com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.TLSConnectionImpl.fireException(Unknow
n Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.TLSConnectionImpl.fireAlertReceived(Un
known Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.record.alert.AlertHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.record.alert.AlertHandler.handleAlertMessages(Unknow
n Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.record.MessageInterpreter.interpretContent(Unknown S
ource)
        at com.certicom.tls.record.MessageInterpreter.decryptMessage(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at com.certicom.tls.record.ReadHandler.processRecord(Unknown Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.record.ReadHandler.readRecord(Unknown Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.record.ReadHandler.readUntilHandshakeComplete(Unknow
n Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.TLSConnectionImpl.completeHandshake(Un
known Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.record.WriteHandler.write(Unknown Source)
        at com.certicom.io.OutputSSLIOStreamWrapper.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65
)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:123)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.j
ava:158)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.
java:363)
        at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpsURLC
onnection.java:37)
        at weblogic.wsee.connection.transport.TransportUtil.getInputStream(Trans
portUtil.java:85)
        at weblogic.wsee.connection.transport.http.HTTPClientTransport.receive(H
TTPClientTransport.java:271)
        at weblogic.wsee.connection.soap.SoapConnection.receive(SoapConnection.j
ava:485)
        at weblogic.wsee.ws.dispatch.client.ConnectionHandler.handleResponse(Con
nectionHandler.java:179)
        at weblogic.wsee.handler.HandlerIterator.handleResponse(HandlerIterator.
java:287)
        at weblogic.wsee.handler.HandlerIterator.handleResponse(HandlerIterator.
java:271)
        at weblogic.wsee.ws.dispatch.client.ClientDispatcher.handleResponse(Clie
ntDispatcher.java:213)
        at weblogic.wsee.ws.dispatch.client.ClientDispatcher.dispatch(ClientDisp
atcher.java:150)
        at weblogic.wsee.ws.WsStub.invoke(WsStub.java:87)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxrpc.StubImpl._invoke(StubImpl.java:339)
        at sips_cn_contract.PaymentService_Stub.processPaymentWebInit(Unknown So
urce)
        at uk.gov.gateway.payments.SipsStartupController.handleRequest(SipsStart
upController.java:73)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.ha
ndle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(Dispatche
rServlet.java:485)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.serviceWrapper(Frame
workServlet.java:342)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServl
et.java:318)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run
(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecuri
tyHelper.java:125)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.jav
a:300)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.jav
a:183)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationActio
n.doIt(WebAppServletContext.java:3686)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationActio
n.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3650)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(Authenticate
dSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:
121)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppS
ervletContext.java:2268)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletC
ontext.java:2174)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.j
ava:1446)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
</bea_fault:stacktrace></detail>]; nested exception is:
```

However in firefox, i have added the certificate, and when i view the wsdl of the web service.It prompts me with the certificate and after i click ok, it renders the wsdl file for secure web service.
Anybody has idea what should I do to make the client working using Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have likely not imported your certificate and key correctly. You can test your keystore by adding the following to a JUnit or something similar:

```
static {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "pkcs12"); // or whatever
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "c:/folder/mycert.p12");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "mypassword");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");
}
```

The `javax.net.debug` property set to `ssl` will print your certificate chain and all other SSL logging, which can be helpful. You'll want to add the certificate, etc. to your application container like you already have in production.

Try debugging with SSL and see what comes of that. More than likely you just need to configure weblogic correctly. Check to see if there are custom SSL endpoint configurations (i.e. when URI is /test/test use keyStore XYZ).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tested the certificate stuff separately in a Standalone java class.But when i deploy the web application on weblogic, it still gives me the same exception.

Answer (score 14):

I think that the real problem is that Weblogic is not using standard Sun HTTPS implementation provided by JDK, but rather uses its own, as apparent on this line:

```
at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpsURLConnection.java:37)
```

The standard Sun implementation class is called `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection`.

As a result, the certificate policy is different inside Weblogic than in a standalone Java program. I just discovered this debugging a similar problem.

This page advises to use a Sun implementation instead of Weblogic:
http://webtech-kapil.blogspot.com/2010/06/javalangclasscastexception.html

They advice to start WL with the following flag:

`-DUseSunHttpHandler=true`

which will use standard Sun's implementation of SSL. However, I personally have not tried this yet.

Thanks,

Igor

Comment: I finally got to use this parameter and can confirm it loads the SUN's implementation and fixes the problem.

Comment: you saved my day. I am getting similar error and this post helps to resolve my problem.

Comment: i just logged in to +1 your answer.

Comment: @yılmaz, appreciate!